# Where can I find the gem package for simplecov that are supporting ruby 1.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-2, simplecov

I have a rather old ruby 1.8.7 + Rails 2.3.8 project which I still need to support. In the project there is a lot of unit test which I use.

And, I would like to have a code coverage report as I had for many years ago using SimpleCov.

But I cannot find the gem files any more. Every gem I can find is only for Ruby 1.9+....

Can you help me?

Comment: https://github.com/simplecov-ruby/simplecov/tags?after=v0.4.2

Comment: That repo is only for Ruby 1.9+ even the oldest tag. Like from the .gemspec file v 0.1.0
```Makes ruby 1.9's code coverage library's results more accessible in an object-oriented manner and adds some sugar on top```. So that repo is out of the question.

Comment: When having simplecov 0.4.1 installed together with simplecov-html 0.4.3, then you get this result when 

```SimpleCov.start -> WARNING: SimpleCov is activated, but you're not running Ruby 1.9+ - no coverage analysis will happen```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer my self. SimpleCov is ONLY for Ruby 1.9+. If I want to see my code coverage I should use rcov, which is ONLY for ruby <=1.8.7.

That solution is perfect for me.